# Validation and Creating unique ID

Tags: mysql, unique-index

Okay - for my project I was asked to identify some validation techniques for a process that we have to transform some data. Let me give you a background.

We receive data from client - we load the file, and only pull in the fields necessary for processing. A few checks are done at this stage. From here we run scripts on the data which essentially does all the heavy lifting. (Dropping duplicates, checking dates, etc). Then it runs through a blackbox system and spits us out results.

We have been notified by client that we are extremely off in our counts for a particular group. roughly $4mill dollars for this one.

We have a process to identify a unique member, by generating a pol_ID, a Suf_ID and with their associated groupname, they are considered unique in our system,  and in our processing system.

We need a process to handle the records for these unique members.
A unique member can have one to many claims associated to their name in a given time period.

When we receive claim information, it is generally handled by using the payor_field + claimno + a generated sequence number (sometimes this sequence number is the last two digits of claimno)...

Ex. Three claims come into system, and after processing through load, we see
   the client has repeated the claimno - since we using the last two digits, it no longer makes them unique and drops a two of the three records. Only retaining the first one.

```
WKS-01100 75.02 - stays
WKS-01100 6000.56 - drops
WKS-01100 560.23 - drops
```

My problem comes into play, because we usually make assumptions on the claimno that if we parse off the last two digits, it is unique, in testing this case we have tried creating an explicit incremental sequence number in another column to consider this unique. Which then doubles our results.

Now my questions are as follows:

Is there another way to make these claims unique? Auto-Increment is not an option. Consider the client can send duplicate claimnos which is where our problem lies, they can potentially recycle their claimno.

Since it's month based, maybe there could be some kind of month id on the end..?

Would any binary representation of the sequence number work? It is an INT data type..
(Also should be noted we deal with historical data that goes back 24 months, and each month we get the next consecutive months data, and we drop the first month in the set)

We are not limited on what we do to transform this claimno so I am open to suggestions...tried to keep it short but let me know if I need to add more info :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a timestamp saved for each claim? A possible solution is to append the timestamp to make the claim unique.

WKS-01100-1330464175

WKS-01100-1327514036

WKS-01100-1341867984

Comment: How would the timestamp be generated?

Comment: MySQL has `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function. It also has `UUID` function that returns universally unique id.

Comment: N.B. has a great suggestion to use UUID. See the documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Okay what If I told you they had to start with 1 and be an integer?